# Entity framework query child on to many

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm struggling with an EF query as below.

The question group table has a 1:n to question_group_question and I don't want to return ones with the removed flag set to try for the question_group_question table

```
from qg in this.Question_Group
                    from qgq in qg.Question_Group_Question
                    where qgq.Question.Removed_Flag==false
                    select qg
```

This runs okay but returns question_group_question that have removed set to true.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: try `from qg in this.Question_Group Where qg.Question_Group_Question.Question.Removed_Flag == false Select qg`

Comment: Nope that won't work as the relationship is 1:n, you can't access REmoved_Flag as it would be a collection

Comment: Yeah.. I'm not sure why I said that.. I must had been tired..

Answer (score 0):

```
from qg in this.Question_Group
                    where qg.Question_Group_Question.Question.Removed_Flag==false                 
                    select qg
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

review this,

```
 from qg in this.Question_Group 
 Where qg.Question_Group_Question.Where(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false).Count() > 0 
 & qg.Question_Group_Question.Any(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false)
 Select qg
```

you can see that `qg.Question_Group_Question.Any(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false)` is returning `true` if **ANY** of the Items (Question) within the Collection (Question_Group_Question) has a member (Removed_Flag) with a specific value (false).

---

If you intend to query/get `Question_Group` entities in which the `Removed_Flag` is false for **ALL** the `Question` entities in the `Question_Group_Question` collection.

```
 from qg in this.Question_Group
 Where qg.Question_Group_Question.Where(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false).Count() > 0 & qg.Question_Group_Question.All(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false)
 Select qg
```

---

from what I can tell of your current Query, you're effectively performing an inner join, so in the relationship of `Question_Group` to `Question_Group_Question` (which is 1:N), you're returning an entity of `Question_Group` for Each `Question_Group_Question`.

That appears to be what you're intending to do, so why not just query on `Question_Group_Question`: (for Question_Group_Question to Question_Group is N:1)

```
 from qgq in this.Question_Group_Question
 where qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false
 select qgq.Question_Group
```

---

Alternatively (and/or additionally), I would advise you to use use DTOs in your queries. Especially if you want to explicitly keep the 1:N structure.

```
class QuestionGroupQuestionPair {
   public Question_Group QuestionGroup {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Question_Group_Question> QuestionCollection {get;set;}
}

IEnumerable<QuestionGroupQuestionPair> query = from qg in this.Question_Group
select new QuestionGroupQuestion() 
    { 
       QuestionGroup = qg,
       QuestionCollection = qg.Question_Group_Question.Where(qgq => qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false) 
    }
```

the `QuestionGroupQuestion` class becomes part of the query expression and is thus expressed in the generated SQL Statement that is executed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it does what I wanted                                          from qgq in this.Question_Group_Question
 where qgq.Question.Removed_Flag == false
 select qgq.Question_Group

Comment: Good tip on the DTO too, the app I currently have doesn't do it this way but is a pattern that can be added to help the data transfer, thanks